# How can I pause an action in real time (Qt5)?

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a function that reads some commands and does things related to that commands. The problem is that I want to pause the program after each command. This is my code:

```
void MainWindow::moveDown(){

    QPoint l = ui->label->pos();
    int x = l.rx();
    int y = l.ry();
    if(y+50 <= 630){
        QPixmap pix(":/resources/img/Penguin.png");
        int w = ui->label->width();
        int h = ui->label->height();
        ui->label->setPixmap(pix.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
        y = y+50;
        ui->label->setGeometry(x, y, 50, 50);
        //sleep(1);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried the `sleep()` function, but it pauses the program before the label starts moving. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this function many years ago that I've been using since. It keeps the event loop going so that the UI doesn't freeze during the sleep. It does this by executing a local event loop for the requested amount of milliseconds. It also aborts the loop if the application wants to quit:

```
/*
 * Sleep for 'ms' milliseconds without freezing the UI.
 */
void sleepLoop(const long ms)
{
    QEventLoop idle_loop;
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &idle_loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &idle_loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    timer.start(ms);
    idle_loop.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I get the  **undefined reference to `MainWindow::sleepLoop(long)'** error and also in the moc file. I have declared the function. How can I solve this? `case 11: _t->sleepLoop((*reinterpret_cast< const long(*)>(_a[1]))); break;` - the moc line

Comment: @ȘtefanAndontjh why are you making it a member function? Just make it a free function, just like I wrote it.